# P3 Profiler and Yoast SEO plugin

Tags: plugin-wp-seo-yoast, profiling

I have profiled my blog with the P3 Plugin and it pointed out that Yoast SEO slows down the site a bit. I then found out that the biggest performance penalty is paid when you "force rewrite" the titles[1], which I am doing.

Now I do have quite an aggressive caching turned on with WP Super Cache. Does it still matter if I force-rewrite the titles then? Or in my case it doesn't change a thing since pages are pre-generated and served as static content?

[1] http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-wordpress-seo-by-yoast-performance-issues-does-it-do-any-good-now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now I do have quite an aggressive caching turned on with WP Super
>   Cache. Does it still matter if I force-rewrite the titles then? Or in
>   my case it doesn't change a thing since pages are pre-generated and
>   served as static content?

Yes it does matter because you are not serving cached content 100% of the time and you also have to think about the time and resources it takes to rebuild the cache.

You eliminate the need to force title rewrites by fixing your theme and replacing whatever is currently being used in the title tags with:

`<title><?php wp_title() ?></title>`

I'm leaving wp_title() blank without any arguments because the plugin is going to filter that content anyway.